# Android Easiest way to Display Twitter feed with a certain hashtag

Tags: android, api, twitter

Is there any possible way to display twitter search feed without authentication (bearer token, Consumer key, Consumer secret)? Can someone help me thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,its not possible due to  security reasons.

For all social login there must be authorization required to access information. but for twitter i found one new solution without login. Please check below link

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-twitter-search-app-project-setup--mobile-13755

This site use following link to search feeds http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=query